# How to print base64 Image coming from WebApi, in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, web-applications

I am going to print an Image (embeded as a property into an object), which retrieved  from a WebApi.

So far, I could load the image and show it perfectly on my page like the following:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{t.Image}}"/>
```

However the problem is I don't know how can I print this image?

I have tried out the following listing but I am faced with crashed google chrome page.

```
   var img= window.open($scope.t.Image);
   img.print();
```

**Question is How can I print the Image?**

This is my Object coming from WebApi:

```
 public class TestImage
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    }
```

and the following is how I call the Get method:

```
  $scope.getData = function (val) {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:2740/GetData', {
            params: {
                name: val
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.t = response.data;
            return response.data;
        });
    };
```

********UPDATED********

```
$scope.imgName = "myImage";
$scope.print = function () {

    var printContents = document.getElementById($scope.imgName);
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');
    popupWin.document.close();
}



<img id="{{imgName}}" ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{t.Image}}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I misread your question...

Try this ...  You will need to assign and ID to the image tag.

```
$scope.printImg = function(imgName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(imgName);
  var popupWin = window.open();
  popupWin.document.open()
  popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Comment: I have done what you said but the problem is `popupWin` is undefined when I watch that in debug mode.

Comment: that doesn't make a lot of sense.  your defining popupwin right above it.

Comment: Ok, try just removing the width and height, also, does {{imgName}} === "myImage" ?  I'll update my answer with width adn height removed.  it might be causing issues and is not necessary.

Comment: In my case the window is opened but onload event doesn't trigger and the window does not print.